# Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all

Tags: apt

Updating apt-get I see the following errors:

```
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all amd64 Packages
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all i386 Packages  
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all amd64 Packages  
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all i386 Packages  
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all amd64 Packages  
Err http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all i386 Packages   
Ign http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all 
Translation-nl_NL                     
Ign http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all Translation-nl  
Ign http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all Translation-en_US
Ign http://php53.dotdeb.org stable/all Translation-en

W: Failed to fetch copy:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/php53.dotdeb.org_dists_stable_all_binary-amd64_Packages  Invalid file format

W: Failed to fetch copy:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/php53.dotdeb.org_dists_stable_all_binary-i386_Packages  Invalid file format
```

I use PHP 5.5.9 so any reference to php53 may be removed.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'php53' /etc/apt`

Comment: @A.B those lines are wrong to me. Their website does not show that as a valid source list line. And why would you even consider adding both i386 and amd64 at the same time? Spells trouble ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the lines in your `sources.list` and in the `list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
sudo sed -i '/php53\.dotdeb\.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i '/php53\.dotdeb\.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

---

*And because you're saying.*

> I use PHP 5.5.9 so any reference to php53 may be removed.

PHP 5.5.9 is in the Ubuntu repositories. You don't need additionally repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the one that offers a debian package for a LAMP stack and NOT [dotdeb.com](http://ww1.dotdeb.com/) (that offers debian installer files for loads of software).

According to their website ([dotdeb.org](https://www.dotdeb.org/mirrors/)) ...

```
Dotdeb supports :

Debian 8.x “Jessie“,
Debian 7.x “Wheezy” and Debian 6.x “Squeeze“
both amd64 and i386 architectures
```

And the apt line for a Dutch server should be ...

```
deb http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/dotdeb/ stable all
deb-src http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/dotdeb/ stable all
```

I would suggest changing your lines to the one above.

And to anyone wanting to do the same please do read: https://serverfault.com/questions/279826/debian-and-dotdeb-packages